# Blurry Images on Website because of CSS?

Tags: html, image, css

Hey guys I have some images that I believe I've sized proportionally but they are showing up blurry.

The issue lies with them being width: 100% but what I don't understand is I've made the images the size of the boxes and bigger but they still appear blurry.

I guess I dont get what is STRECHING the images, since they should all be to size.

[image]

Could the issue be with my responsive CSS? If I take off width: 100% the images seem to go to my responsive size.. ~ 310px x 180px.

[image]

Normally I'd think this was a background-size: issue but I'm at a loss for what could be causing this.

```
Regular Code:
.special-offers { margin: 0 0 150px 0; position: relative; }
.special-offers .banner { width: 33.33%; max-height: 270px; float: left; text-align: center; position: relative; }
.special-offers .banner a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2; }
.special-offers .banner a img { position: relative; z-index: 3; width: 100%; }

Responsive Code:
.special-offers { margin: 0 0 30px 0; }
.special-offers .banner { width: 100%; }
.special-offers .banner a { width: 300px; height: 180px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
.special-offers .banner h4 { margin: 0; }
.special-offers .banner a img { width: 300px; }
```

any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: The one with the water bottle... What's the original image size?

Comment: The image is current 1250px by 750px. I figured a bigger image would result in no blurring.

Comment: Well, that's exactly why I was asking, cause if you put a 300 X nnn px image and make it bigger... the browser cannot invent quality - it can only interpret neighbor pixels colors resulting in a (*blur* is quite inaccurate) upscaled image with quality loss.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I dont get what is STRECHING the images, since they should all be to size.

In your example, that doesn't appear to be the case.  Your real image size is smaller than you expect.

Comment: Interesting.. It seems that when I am putting the images into Shopify, they are being automatically resized. This may be an entirely different issue on it's own.

Comment: @Alan Yeah, Shopify will do that.

Comment: Incase anyone is monitoring this thread. I went into my setting_shema.json under the Config folder. Here I was able to locate the culprit.  {
        "type": "image",
        "id": "banner_2_image.jpg",
        "label": "Image",
        "max-width": 310,
        "max-height": 180,
        "info": "(max size: 310px x 180px)"
      }, --- Editing the max-width and max-height fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I located settings_shema.json in the Shopify Config Folder.

Here I found

```
 {
    "type": "image",
    "id": "banner_2_image.jpg",
    "label": "Image",
    "max-width": 1310,
    "max-height": 1180,
    "info": "(max size: 310px x 180px)"
  },
```

Editing the max-width: and max-height allowed me to fix the images. Essentially shopify was resizing the images down, and then I was trying to make the small images 100%.